# Magento custom ACL return TRUE by default

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, acl

I have defined an acl for a tab in Manage Customer

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <manage>
                                <children>
                                    <managepoint translate="title">
                                        <title>Manage Point</title>
                                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    </managepoint>
                                </children>
                            </manage>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Using this code

```
public function canShowTab(){
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('customer/manage/managepoint'))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

It is expacted that by default for all users under any user role except admin role Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('customer/manage/managepoint') should return FALSE but actually it returns TRUE, but if I check then uncheck this ACL for a perticular Role then ACL starts working as expected.

Can anybody tell me why Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('customer/manage/managepoint') is returning FALSE by default.

Comment: After creating acl I'm taking care of clearing var/cache, var/session and logging IN/OUT for testig.
My core_session table is also empty

Comment: while testing I found that Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('customer/manage/garbage_value') return FALSE, just whatever acl I define returns TRUE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took time but after proper testing I came on conclusion on behaviour of Magento with ACL.

Mangento stores Role resources in admin_role table with permission deny/allow. So whenever we create new role then there is no entry for that resource to any role in admin_role and isAllowed will return TRUE value by default. But hereafter if we create new roles and with our custom ACL unchecked then admin_role saves entry with "deny" permission. So isAllowed will work as expacted.
Thus after creating a new ACL either we have to go to every role and save these roles once or go to admin_role table and provide entries for all role_id's

Comment: I've found this to be some particularly annoying behaviour. The default value for isAllowed is true, but looking at the resources tab for that role, the checkbox is un-ticked.

Comment: @Cags As it is explained in answer that you have to save role once as it is once to make new acl working.

Comment: Indeed, I find this particular annoying though. Just raised a question over on magento.stackexchange.com to see if anybody has any experience of automating this process.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution itself, and as many I find this to be particularly annoying.
So here is a way if you have many roles and you want to quickly add a deny you can run this SQL command

```
-- Add roles to DENY
INSERT INTO admin_rule
SELECT null, role_id, 'admin/path/to/your/acl', null, 0, 'G', 'deny'  FROM admin_role WHERE user_id = 0 AND role_id NOT IN (1, 20);

-- Add roles to ALLOW
INSERT INTO admin_rule
SELECT null, role_id, 'admin/path/to/your/acl', null, 0, 'G', 'allow'  FROM admin_role WHERE user_id = 0 AND role_id IN (1, 20);
```

This script can be sent at the same time as your code.